# Website not showing on smartphone - GWT & Tomcat

Tags: css, tomcat, gwt, smartphone

I developed a GWT project and hosted it on a Tomcat server.
As I wanted the website to have different visualization basing on the resolution of the device used, I added the @media tags in the stylesheet.

```
    .infoUtente {
    background-color: #e0fbe0;
    border-style: solid dotted;
    border-color: #1b6b52;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.aboutUs {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #e0fbe0;
    border-style: double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #1b6b52;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.statsLbl {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #1b6b52;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*desktop*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .titolo {
        text-align: left;
        color: #1b6b52;
        margin-left: 30px;
        font-size: 40px;
        text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em grey;
        padding-top: auto;
        padding-bottom: auto;
    }
}

/*smartphones*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .titolo {
        text-align: left;
        color: #1b6b52;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em grey;
        padding-top: auto;
        padding-bottom: auto;
    }
}

.refreshBtn {
    width: 45px;
    height: 55px;
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .loginLbl {
        font: bold 15px arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #1b6b52;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .loginLbl {
        font: bold 11px arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #1b6b52;
    }
}

.loginPanel {
    float: right;
    /*padding-top: 23px;*/
}

.debug {
    border-style: double;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .statsPanel {
        border-style: double;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: #acbeca;
        border-width: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        bottom: 40%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .statsPanel {
        display: none;
    }
}

.cellCol {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .menuPnl {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .menuPnl {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}

.centerPnl {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*nascondo northpanel e porto titolo e login panel a sinistra?*/
.northPanel {
    background-color: #e6f0b4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: #1b6b52;
    border-width: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .westPanel {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .westPanel {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .southPanel {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .southPanel {
        display: none;
    }
}

.bottomBtn {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #1b6b52;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.twitter {
    line-height: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .legendPnl {
        border-left-style: double;
        border-left-color: #1b6b52;
        border-left-width: 5px;
        border-bottom-style: double;
        border-bottom-color: #1b6b52;
        border-bottom-width: 5px;
        background-color: #e6f0b4;
        width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: 2px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .legendPnl {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-style: double;
        border-color: #1b6b52;
        border-width: 5px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.mainPanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e6f0b4;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .leftButton {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: #1b6b52;
        color: white;
        font: normal 15px arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .leftButton {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: #1b6b52;
        color: white;
        font: normal 10px arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .loginButton {
        width: 50px;
        height: 32px;
        background-color: #1b6b52;
        color: white;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .loginButton {
        width: 40px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #1b6b52;
        color: white;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .loginBox {
        width: 100px;
        height: 32px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .loginBox {
        width: 60px;
        height: 18px;
    }
}

.slideShow {
    background-color: #32353c;
    border-style: double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #1b6b52;
    border-width: 5px
}


.userInfo {
    text-align: center;
    color: #1b6b52;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.registrazionePnl {
    width: 18%;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #1b6b52;
    border-width: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .inserisciPnl {
        border-style: double;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: #1b6b52;
        border-width: 5px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    .inserisciPnl {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

#closeButton {
    margin: 15px 6px 6px;
}
```

If I try to resize the browser on a PC, the visualization correctly changes (some panels and buttons disappear) and the webpage has the wanted behaviour.
But if I try to access the website from a smartphone, nothing is showed.
Do you think it's a .css correlated issue or a more general problem with tomcat and smartphone access?
thanks

Comment: it's not a tomcat issue. try to play with the css until you figure it out, if you get rid of the css most likely you'll be able to view the page from the smartphone

Comment: @user905374 removing the .css did not make the trick